# How to manage the different pixel size for a CNN?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a convolutional neural network such as U-Net for a segmentation task and in input images with the same spatial resolution (256x256) but different pixel size due to the acquisition process. Specifically, every image has FoV 370x370mm 256/256 pixel, but a different zoom, for example an image might have 2.7/1.8 px/mm and another image 2.4/1.7 px/mm. 
Considering the FoV the pixel size should be 370/256=1.44mm x pixel but with a zoom of 2.7/1.8 px/mm which is the pixel size in this case ? I thought 1.8/2.7= 0.67mm but I am not sure. 
Why should I have the same in-plane resolution (pixel size) for each image when I train my CNN and not only the same spatial resolution (256x256 px) ?